# How to make background-image responsive after resize windows with specific width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, responsive-design

I want to make background-image responsive after resize windows with specific width, like this main img http://preview.oklerthemes.com/porto/5.4.0/demo-construction.html.

Comment: you mean logo image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you can find in the **[construction site example](http://preview.oklerthemes.com/porto/5.4.0/demo-construction.html)** using the **[developer tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)**:

[image]

You can set the `background-size` to `cover`.

```
.element {
    background-image: url('*');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Where `*` in the `url()` is the path to your image.

Or simply use the shorthand version:

```
.element {
    background: url('*') no-repeat center center/cover;
}
```

Comment: no, cover stretch too quickly the image, i want that the img resize linear after tot windows width resize, like in http://preview.oklerthemes.com/porto/5.4.0/demo-construction.html

Comment: Have you tried using your browser's dev tools to check this web page? Please have a look at my updated answer above. Always keep this in mind - that using `cover` , especially for sliders requires your images to have the exact same aspect ratio if you want them to display accordingly.

Comment: sorry, you're right, i forget to specified that my background-div is fixed to make the parallax effect, so i need height obbligatory